# Result not matching up to Set Variable

Tags: c++

I am scratching my brain off trying to figure this one out.

Why are running backs getting 60+ carries a game with this code? I just don't get it.
The team is an array, this for loop is only supposed to run 25 times AT MOST. I've even tried setting the for loop to (int g = 1; g < 20; g++) and yet still it is coming up with 60+ carries a game for no reason. Any help?

```
hold3 = rand() % (10 - 15 + 1) + 15;

for(int g = 1; g < hold3; g++){
    
    hold = rand() % (15 - team[u].elusivness[2] + 1) + team[u].elusivness[2];
    
    if(hold == 13 || hold == 14){
        
        team[u].carries[2]++;
        
        
        hold = rand() % (17 - team[u].strength[2] + 1) + team[u].strength[2];
        
        if(hold == 13){
            
            team[u].rushingtouchdowns[2]++;
            hold = rand() % 25 + 5;
            team[u].rushingyards[2] += hold;
            
            
        }else{
            
            hold = rand() % (12 - team[u].speed[2] + 1) + team[u].speed[2];
            
            if(hold == 12){
            hold = rand() % 15 + 5;
            team[u].rushingyards[2] += hold;
            }else{
            hold = rand() % 5 + 1;
            team[u].rushingyards[2] += hold;    
            }
            
            
            
        }
        
        
        
        
    }
    
    
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are trying getting mod from deviser below 0. hold3 = rand() % **(10 - 15 + 1)** + 15;